# R: par(mfrow=c(4,2)) not behaving as expected

Tags: r, pdf, linechart, quantmod

I am trying to pretty-print 80 pages of stock graphs and would like to get roughly 8 per page (4 rows, 2 columns) for 10 pages. In production I will be getting stocks from a CSV file and then looping through a list.

I expected 4 rows of 2 columns on a 1-page pdf, but instead created an 8-page pdf. Any hints as to how to fix this?

**foo.R**

```
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library(quantmod)))
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)

# get 8 symbols
getSymbols("AAPL")
getSymbols("GOOG")
getSymbols("FB")
getSymbols("TSLA")
getSymbols("GM")
getSymbols("F")
getSymbols("INTC")
getSymbols("AMD")

pdf(file="foo.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(4,2))

lineChart(AAPL)
lineChart(GOOG)
lineChart(FB)
lineChart(TSLA)
lineChart(GM)
lineChart(F)
lineChart(INTC)
lineChart(AMD)

dev.off()
```

Comment: You can try to put `par(mfrow=c(4,2))` before the `pdf(file="foo.pdf")` line.

Comment: No, `par` should be applied to the current device, i.e. after calling `pdf(...)`.

Comment: To be able to answer this question, we must know what `lineChart` is. Where is the function defined?

Comment: If line chart is based on the `grid` graphic structure, as `ggplot2` and `lattice` are, then `par` has no effect. If that is the case, look into the `gridExtras` package. There are many questions involving this with `gridExtras`.

Comment: @MrGrumble: I think lineChart is syntactic sugar for chartSeries, but I can not confirm that. https://www.quantmod.com/documentation/chartSeries.html

Comment: @MrGrumble: (lineChart,barChart, and candleChart) are convenience wrappers to these different styles of chartSeries.